# How to add unique entries of Map<String,Object> to List<Object> using Java Streams?

Tags: java, java-8, stream

I have a `List<Object>` element in Java which contains `Map<String, String>` before adding a new `Map<String, String>` I would like to know if there is any `Map` in `List` already has that `Key`, if so do not add it. If there is no matching then add it.

I am trying to use the flatMap approach but getting a bit confused halfway through and unable to find an efficient approach. Hence, Looking for some suggestions on efficient and less processing approaches.

Also, if I am doing the check on the empty list then it's failing as well and not adding the values. I would like to do the check for the key before adding every map if not present then add it, if present skip it.

Following is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("String Element");

        Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put("key1", "value1");
        list.add(map1);

        Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("key2", "value2");
        list.add(map2);

        Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<>();
        map3.put("key3", "value3");
        list.add(map3);

        System.out.println("Before Duplicate Addition : " + list);
        Map<String,String> dupChecker = list.stream().filter(c -> c instanceof Map<?, ?>).map(c -> (Map<String, String>) c).flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream()).collect(Collectors.toMap(en->en.getKey(), en-> en.getValue(), (r1, r2) -> r1));
        
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s impossible to “find an efficient approach” because the whole setup is inherently inefficient. If you have constraints on what to add to a collection, don’t use a `List` which requires a linear search each time. Further, the phrase “already has *that* Key” suggests that you only have singleton maps, which makes `HashMap` a bad choice. And begs the question why you are using a list of maps at all. Whatever your actual task is, there are better data structures for the task, for sure.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your response. I would like to use the `List` with `HashMap` as that has been used already in other parts of the code and it's not coming from my application but rather an external application. Can you please provide some suggestion on how to achieve this as I am unable to make it work as of now?

Comment: That doesn’t save you from defining the requirements. Does the new map really have only one key? As otherwise, you have to define whether you want to check for any matching key or for a map having all the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the problem into 3 steps:

- collect the entries (`groupsByKey`)
- group by key and get the number of entries per key (`groupsByKey`)
- filter the entries having a count equal to 1 (`finalResult`)

```java
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = list.stream()
        .filter(c -> c instanceof Map<?, ?>)
        .map(c -> (Map<String, String>) c)
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .toList();

Map<String, Long> groupsByKey = entries.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.counting()));

Map<String, String> finalResult = entries.stream()
        .filter(e -> groupsByKey.get(e.getKey()) == 1)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: There is no need to do what you are doing in three steps. Most notably, there is no need to collect into a `List`, just to perform one subsequent stream operation. The `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(…))` step could done right with the first stream, without producing a `List`. But how does this solve the OP’s task to “*check for the key before adding*” at all?